# Join two tables together in a helper table based on relationship

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

***User: phone_number, coupon***

***Customers: customer_id, coupon***

I want to create a helper table that links user and customer_id together based on the certain coupon. The third table will have three fields: coupon, phone_number, customer_id which should be retrieved from those two tables. I tried **Inner Join** but doesn't seem like work. Could someone help please?

```
SELECT customers.customer_id as customer_id, users.phone as 
phone
FROM linked_customers_users 
INNER JOIN customers
ON linked_customers_users.customer_id = customers.customer_id
INNER JOIN users
ON linked_customers_users.phone = users.phone
```

Comment: This doesn't actually exist right? `linked_customers_users ` I'm confused, you started out talking about 2 tables.

Comment: @SQLChao this is the third table that I created already

Comment: Does the `linked_customers_users` actually have data in it? Or do you need to `INSERT INTO`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

Try `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT customers.customer_id as customer_id, users.phone as 
phone
FROM linked_customers_users 
LEFT JOIN customers
ON linked_customers_users.customer_id = customers.customer_id
LEFT JOIN users
ON linked_customers_users.phone = users.phone
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies as commenter pointed out you are using mysql. You can always try emulate a full outer join with (note this will remove duplicates if you have them):

```
SELECT * FROM linked_customers_users 
LEFT JOIN users ON linked_customers_users.coupon = users.coupon
UNION
SELECT * FROM linked_customers_users 
RIGHT JOIN users ON linked_customers_users.coupon = users.coupon
```

Comment: No it won't because MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`